# SQL find Peak Hour and Peak off Hour from the table

Tags: sql-server

In my table data will be inserted frequently. We need to find out in which hour less amount of data is inserted into server. We have inserted the data inserted time also in our table.

```
Create Table Order (
    id int,
    Storeid int,
    orderreceivedTime datetime
)
```

How to find peak hour and peak off hour of the Order table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple aggregate query something like this will work

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) inserts, DATEPART(HOUR,orderreceivedTime) hour
  FROM order
 GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,orderreceivedTime)
```